# document.write entire page, not just frame

Tags: javascript, frames, document.write

I've got an HTML page with several frames. I run a javascript in one of the frames to rewrite the entire page, i.e. get rid of all frames and rewrite the whole page. But document.write only writes the frame it's written in. How can I do this with javascript?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

If the frame and container are both on the same domain, you can use `parent.document` to access the whole HTML page.

If they are on different domain, you cannot do this due to security restrictions.

Comment: This is now doing something even harder to understand, if you don't mind taking a look (http://lloydphillips.co.uk/germanicus/). It works fine the first time, but multiple searches don't rewrite the whole page, they load at the bottom.

Comment: I've changed that since to go back to document.write from parent.document.write because only rewriting the frame is less of a nuisance that what parent.document.write was doing

Answer (score 0):

The global javascript object `window.frames` contains all frames. From this point you can edit all parts of your page.